# Python string split by template date

Tags: date, arraylist

I built a function that returns a list of date and time - ['2/12/2018', '15: 55 ']
Or in different order ['15: 55 ',' 2/12/2018 ']

How can I build a code that will always take only the **date**?

Comment: Return a dict/tuple/object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you return them as a String. In that case what about this:

```
list_of_lists = [["2/12/2018", "15:55"], ["23/12/2018", "22:32"]]

for list in list_of_lists:
  for x in list:
    if(x.find(":") != -1):
      print(x)
```

That should do it.